# Indicator random variables of two events

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Before someone closes this question or marks it as a duplicate, I would like to point out that this question is based on another identical asked question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271402/let-a-be-an-event-and-let-ia-be-the-associated-indicator-random-variable). It never got a real answer so this is my own attempt at solving the problem.

Let A be an event, and let $I_{A}$ be the associated indicator random variable: $I_{A} (\omega)=1$ if $ω∈A$, and $I_{A}(ω)=0$ if $ω∉A$. Similarly, let $I_{B}$ be the indicator of another event, $B$. Suppose that, $P(A)=p$, $P(B)=q$, and $P(A∪B)=r$.

To find $E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]$  in terms of $p$,$q$ and $r$

$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=E[(I_{A}−I_{B})(I_{A}−I_{B})]$$
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=E(I^2_{A}-2I_{A}I_{B}+I^2_{B}]$$
Given $I^2_=I_$ and $I_I_=I_{∩}$, then
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=E[I_{A}-2I_{A∩B}+I_{B}]$$
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=E[I_{A}]-2E[I_{A∩B}]+E[I_{B}]$$
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=P(A)-2P(A∩B)+P(B)$$
Given $(∩)=()+()−(∪)$, then
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=P(A)-2(P(A)+P(B)-(∪))+P(B)$$
$$E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]=2(∪)-P(A)-P(B)=2r-p-q$$

I am not completely certain about going from $-2I_{A∩B}$ to $-2E[I_{A∩B}]$

What I would like to know, is this transition legit?

If so, determine $\text{Var}(I_{A}−I_{B})$ in terms of $p$, $q$ and $r$ by substituting.

Given $()=E[]^2−(E[])^2$, then

$$(I_{A}−I_{B})=E[I_{A}−I_{B}]^2−(E[I_{A}−I_{B}])^2$$
$$(I_{A}−I_{B})=E[(I_{A}−I_{B})^2]−(E[I_{A}]−E[I_{B}])^2$$
$$(I_{A}−I_{B})=2r-p-q−(p−q)^2$$

Anyone feel free to show another method or to correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks okay.

> I am not completely certain about going from $−2I_{A∩B}$ to $−2E[I_{A∩B}]$
>
> What I would like to know, is this transition legit?

It is legitimate because you are not doing *that*.   What is happening is the Linearity of Expectation, vis a vis:$$\mathsf E(X-2Y)=\mathsf E(X)-2~\mathsf E(Y)$$

Comment: Yep, Linearity of Expectation makes sense in this case scenario @GrahamKemp

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

$(I_A-I_B)^2$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ and can easily be recognized as $I_{A\Delta B}$ where $A\Delta B$ denotes the [symmetric difference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of $A$ and $B$.

So we find directly that:$$\mathbb E(I_A-I_B)^2=P(A\Delta B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: The beauty of symmetry :) Now just substitute in $(∩)=()+()−(∪)$, then the terms and it's done.

Comment: After all $(_−_)^2 $ is a quadratic equality and, if I think about it, is similar to the quadratic formula which is used to calculate the golden ration, perfect symmetry and whatsoever.